# Get only one value from the table using LINQ

Tags: linq, select, subquery

I have a Customer Table and a Address Table (customer_id,                                                 address_forename, address_surname, address_street, address_city, address_zip,
address_storedtime) where customer_id as a foreign key.

One customer can have several address.

Now I am trying to get only the last entered address using LINQ as bellow which should allow me put the address in a string and return that:
CODE:

```
var customerAddress = (from c in myDB.address
                       where (c.customer_id == customerId)
                       select new
                       {
                           c.customer_id,
                           c.address_forename,
                           c.address_surname,
                           c.address_street,
                           c.address_city,
                           c.address_zip,
                           c.address_storedtime
                       }).GroupBy(g => new
                       {
                           Customer = .customer_id,
                           Address = g.address_forename + " " + g.address_surname + " " + g.address_street + " " +        g.address_city + " " + g.address_zip 
                       }).Select(g => new
                       {
                           g.Key.Customer,
                           g.Key.Address,   
                           StoredTime = g.Max(x => x.address_storedtime)
                       }).Disinct();/*First();*/

string result = "";

foreach (var ad in customerAddress)
{
    if (ad.Address != null)
    {
        result = ad.Address;
    }
    break;
}

return result;
```

I am getting same address string for different addresses in DB for the Customer whereas I am trying to get only one.

Comment: In this part of your code: GroupBy(g => new { Customer = .customer_id, Address = g.address_forename ... isn't ".customer_id" supposed to be "g.customer_id"?

Answer (score 2):

Since you're already filtering by customer id, the grouping clause isn't necessary. You should be able to just order the results for the customer descending and project the address much more simply.

```
var customerAddress = (from c in myDB.address
                        where (c.customer_id == customerId)
                        orderby c.address_storedtime descending
                        select c.address_forename + " " + c.address_surname + " " + c.address_street + " " +        c.address_city + " " + c.address_zip)
                      .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `foreach` by

```
var result =
    customerAdress.Any(ad => ad.Address != null) 
    ? customerAdress.Last(ad => ad.Address != null).Address
    : default(string);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer but I am getting a huge error which I have no clue:LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method '<>f__AnonymousType22`3[System.Int32,System.String,System.DateTime] Last[<>f__AnonymousType22`3](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[<>f__AnonymousType22`3[System.Int32,System.String,System.DateTime]], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[<>f__AnonymousType22`3[System.Int32,System.String,System.DateTime],System.Boolean]])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: and I wanted to get the result for only one time. But it shows (using my code example) me 4 times as there are 4 different address in the adddress table

Comment: :LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method '<>f__AnonymousType22`3[System.Int32,System.String,System.DateTime] Last[<>f__AnonymousType22`3](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[<>f__AnonymousType22`3[Syste‌​m.Int32,System.String,System.DateTime]], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[<>f__AnonymousType22`3[System.‌​Int32,System.String,System.DateTime],System.Boolean]])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression